# how to update a text field on a button pressed with a http result?

Tags: flutter

The example in flutter doc only shows during initState not onPressed.

I wonder what the correct syntax, to update a text field with a button press that triggers an async http request.

```
onPressed: () async {
                await http
                    .get(Uri.parse('https://localhost:5001/api/Blog'))
                    .then((value) => setState(() {
                          _httpResult = value.body;
                        }));
              }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Can you provide context or code or some dummy data/ code so that we can understand?

Comment: CORS issue on Chrome web I think. Thanks guys. Also I needed to use universal_io instead of dart:io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could add more information on it that would be helpful from what I understand:

You’re trying to update a text field, from a button press that fetched content from an url?

If so then the textfield is filled with a variable so in your StatefulWidget class you
Define:

```
final String yourText = “text blah blah”;
```

Then in your widget:

```dart
Text(“${widget.yourText}”)
```

And then on the button onPress

```dart
Onpress: () async{
   try{
     await [yourhttpcall].then(
    (value) => 
    setState(() {
       widget.yourText = value;});
    );

   } catch(e) {
     print(e);
   }
}
```

Not sure if this is what you mean?
Again with the info you provided,
It’s hard to go into specifics.